# Delete asterix from string in a list

Tags: java, string

I have a program in which it generates the number of random words i want it to have. and i have the option to add a word or delete a word. Every time a new word is added a "*" must be placed next to the new word, but it should disappear once I perform the next action. for example:

> dasaf egsdf bgftht
>
> ***then i add a word***
>
> asfww* dasaf egsdf bgftht
>
> ***then i add another word***
>
> asfww bfehw* dasaf egsdf bgftht
>
> ***then i delete a word***
>
> asfww bfehw egsdf bgftht

my issue is that I cant seem to figure out how to make the asterik disappear. so my problem is that this happens:

> asfww* dasaf egsdf bgftht
>
> ***then i add a word***
>
> asfww* bfehw* dasaf egsdf bgftht

this is my code to add a word

```
if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
    {

         L1.addInOrder(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5).toLowerCase()+"*");
        L1.display();
    }
```

this is my addInOrder method

```
public void addInOrder(String word)
   {
           Node temp = new Node(word);
           Node current = head;
           Node prev = head;
           while (current != null && temp.getData().compareTo(current.getData())>0)
           {
                   prev = current;
                   current = current.getNext();
           }
           if (head==null)
           {
                   head = temp;
           }
           else if (current==null)
           {
                   prev.setNext(temp);
           }
           else if (head.getNext()!=null && temp.getData().compareTo(head.getData())>0)
           {
                   temp.setNext(prev.getNext());
                   prev.setNext(temp);
           }
           else if (temp.getData().compareTo(head.getData())<=0)
           {
                   temp.setNext(head);
                   head = temp;
           }
   }
```

my delete method

```
public boolean delete(String x)
   {
       Node find = search(x);
       if (find!=null)
       {
           if (find.equals(head))
           {
               head = find.getNext();
               return true;
           }
           Node word = head;

           while(word!=null)
           {
               if (find.equals(word.getNext()))
               {
                   word.setNext(find.getNext());
                   return true;
               }
               word = word.getNext();
           }
       }
       System.out.println("That word is not in this list!\n");
       return false ;
   }
```

Comment: Why don't you remember the last inserted word for an easy lookup?

Comment: could you elaborate on that?

Comment: the asterik is in the first part of my code.    L1.addInOrder(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5).toLowerCase()+"*");

Comment: @user5335920 Create a private field like `Node last` and in your insertion step you simply do a `last = temp`. Now you're easily getting the last inserted element.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment section you should setup a quick link to the last inserted element. The second step is to create the method which removes the '*' from your String. This method should be called before every computation on your list.

```
private Node last = null;

private void preprocess() {
    if (last != null) {
        last.value = last.value.substring(0, last.value.length() - 1);
    }
}

public void addInOrder(String word) {
    preprocess();
    Node temp = new Node(word);
    last = temp;
    Node current = head;
    Node prev = head;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two simple solutions here:

1) The one I consider the simplest

Don't add an asterisk to the word itself, just add the asterisk when outputting the list.

There are a few ways to do that. The most simple way is:

1. Add a insertionOrder field to the Node class
2. Keep an object counter that is incremented in addInOrder and decreased in delete.

By doing that you can easily identify which was the last inserted element and print the asterisk right there.

When you output the list, just check if the `insertionOrder == object counter` and print the asterisk after the work when you reach it.

The other solution is to keep a reference to the last added object and remove the asterisk from the referenced object when you add a new one and then update the reference to the newly created object.